# Creating "union type" with already defined classes

Tags: kotlin

I have two `classes` which are DTO's

```
class FooDto (
    val a: String,
    val b: Double,
)

class BarDto (
    val c: String,
    val d: String,
)
```

Now, I want define a third `AnotherDto` where I set the type of a property to either `BartDto` or `FooDto`.

```
class AnotherDto (
    val e: FooDto || BarDto
)
```

This obviously does not work. I [read](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-using-sealed-classes-kotlin/#what-sealed-classes) about `sealed classes`, which would look sth like this

```
sealed class Menu{
   data class PIZZA(val name: String, val size:String, val quantity:Int):Menu()
   data class BURGER(val quantity:Int, val size:String): Menu()
   data class CHICKEN(val quantity:Int, val pieces:String):Menu()
}
```

However, this requires me to define all the variables (like `name: String` and `quanitity: Int`) again. This is not what I want, I simply want to reuse my previously defined `FooDto` and `BarDto` without duplicating.

So this

```
sealed class FooBar{
   data class Foo(val a: String, val b: Double):FooBar()
   data class Bar(val c: String, val d: String): FooBar()
}
```

is kind of pointless because I have `FooDto` and `BarDto` already written and they are used somewhere else. I want sth like this

```
sealed class FooBar{
   FooDto:FooBar()
   BarDto: FooBar()
}
```

Which obviously does not work.

How do I reuse my already written `DTO`s `FooDto` and `BarDto` to make a "union type" which I can assign as a data type to a variable in Kotlin?

Comment: How about a `sealed class AnotherDto` with subclasses `AnotherDtoThatHoldsFoo` and `AnotherDtoThatHoldsBar`?

Comment: You can combine the `sealed class` with your existing classes like ```sealed class FooBar { data class Foo(dto: FooDto): FooBar; data class Bar(dto: BarDto): FooBar }```. Or you can use `sealed interface` and make your existing classes implement them (if all of them are in the same package). And then use interface for `FooDto || BarDto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should reject regular inheritance here. Also, a common interface may well be more appropriate than a sealed class.

If you want this:

```
class AnotherDto (
    val e: FooDto || BarDto
)
```

Then `FooDto` and `BarDto` *must* implement some kind of common functionality in order for the property `e` to be useful.

So, whatever common functionality that is, write it in an interface<sup>1</sup>:

```
interface Dto {
   fun doSomethingUseful()
}
```

Then you can implement the interface in `FooDto` and `BarDto`<sup>2</sup> and have:

```
class AnotherDto {
    val e: Dto
}
```

This still doesn't look finished though because presumably you want `AnotherDto` to look like a regular `Dto` object. Then you can use the [delegation feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html), and `AnotherDto` will stand in the place of whichever other `Dto` is passed into its constructor:

```
class AnotherDto(otherDto: Dto) : Dto by otherDto {
    fun doSomethingElseUseful() {
        // something else useful
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Sealed/abstract classes are also possible, but an interface is more flexible when implementing classes are less coupled

<sup>2</sup>Yes, it involves changing those classes; but a union type would not be useful without a shared interface at the least (unless you are going to employ reflection or similar, which must surely be a last resort)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `Either`-class. You can use a pre-existing one from a library like Arrow (https://apidocs.arrow-kt.io/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/index.html), or implement one yourself like this:

```kotlin
sealed interface Either<out L, out R>
data class Left<L>(val value: L) : Either<L, Nothing>
data class Right<R>(val value: R) : Either<Nothing, R>
```

At the call-site, you could now do this:

```kotlin
val fooDto = FooDto("Hi", 5.0)
val anotherClass = AnotherClass(Left(fooDto))
```